# failing to instantiate an object through a constructor in java

Tags: java, swing, constructor, windowbuilder

i'm trying to instantiate an object through a constructor from another class in a different package , and i get an error saying

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       The constructor Utilisateur(String, String, String, String, String, String, float, String, String, String) is undefined

i think it has to do with the way i declared my setters but i'm not sure, hopefully you'll know

**these are the variables, setters(not all of them), and constructor in common.Utilisateur.java**

```
private static String login;
private static String password;
    public static void setLogin(String login) {
        Utilisateur.login = login;
    }

    public static void setPassword(String password) {
        Utilisateur.password = password;
    }
    public Utilisateur(String login,
                       String password,
                       String nom,
                       String prenom,
                       String sexe,
                       String date,
                       float poids,
                       String adresse,
                       String telephone,
                       String email) {
        setLogin(login);
        setPassword(password);
        setNom(nom);
        setPrenom(prenom);
        setSexe(sexe);
        setDate(date);
        setPoids(poids);
        setAdresse(adresse);
        setTelephone(telephone);
        setEmail(email);
    }
```

**constructor call in views.connexion.java**

```
Utilisateur user = new Utilisateur(login.getText(),
                                   password.getText(),
                                   nom.getText(),
                                   prenom.getText(),
                                   sexe.getSelection().getActionCommand(),
                                   date,
                                   Float.parseFloat(poids.getText()),
                                   adresse.getText(),
                                   telephone.getText(), email.getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume, that the package is working with outdated classes and either the package containing `Utilisateur` should be re-compiled or the depending package be updated. On a side note, it's highly advisable to reduce the number of parameters by i.e. using the `Builder` pattern in order to make it more manageable.